# Git on Windows: Where is pageant stored for GIT-Bash environment

Tags: git, ssh, putty

Starting with GIT, I set the plink-path (which is set via the GIT-installation process) to the GIT_SSH environment variable.

Later then I reinstalled PuTTY again and by this the path moved to the default place (C:\Program Files\PuTTY). This works fine with the Windows-command shell but not with the GIT Bash. GIT Bash still looks for it at the old place.

I wonder now where the BASH has stored this and how I might change it.

This is what I get from BASH:

```
$ git clone <user>@<server>:<repository-path> 
Cloning into 'devtools'... 
error: cannot spawn <oldPuttyPath>\plink.exe: Invalid argument 
fatal: unable to fork
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today it's gone. Seems to be a cache problem. Reboot solved it, git clone if fine now

Answer (score 2):

You can add the path to `plink.exe` in the `~/.bashrc` file :

```
export GIT_SSH='/c/Program Files/.../putty/plink.exe'
```

To reload the configuration, run `source ~/.bashrc`.